# How to AB Test a particular component across the whole site?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, ab-testing

I want to do a AB test for the navigation module across the whole site.
I know AB/Multivariate tests are usually page specific.

Is there any way to do AB Testing across a whole site? So, we can change something across the whole site and see if it affects the conversion in any way?

I'm not sure, but is Split URL testing the way to go here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as opinion-based because it's essentially a request for a tool. (Requests for tools tend to be a bad fit for a Q&A site because there's no one right answer, and answers tend to become outdated.) That said, check out [Optimizely](http://optimizely.com/); it should allow you to change a component across the site.

Comment: @GrahamHerrli Okay. Will keep that in mind. :)

Comment: @GrahamHerrli While I can see where you get the "tool" aspect from, I don't believe it's the only way of seeing the question - I read it more as a methodology question.  So I believe it is answerable in a way that doesn't become too outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the tool you use (for instance Visual website optimiser or optimizely) you can target the whole site in the URL Targeting setting by simply changing the setting to URL Contains and putting it in like so > yourdomainnamehere.whatever

or by using matches regex

/yourdomain.whatever/

Comment: I figured that, but should I choose AB Testing or Split URL testing in that case? I'm using VWO btw

Comment: Nevermind! Got it. VWO's help section had a thorough answer on it

Comment: Yeah the Knowledge base is quite useful, just bear in mind to use as a setTimeout function as they define in their best practice, it'll help get around some of the flicker

https://vwo.com/knowledge/vwo-editor-best-practices/

For anyone else interested this would be run as a A/B Test